# Disable column wrapping in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm currently faced with the following situation:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col col-auto"></div>
</div>
```

So, the first column will occupy the space available that is not being filled by the second column

i.e.
[ |--------column1--------| |column2| ]

My issue is when the content inside `column1` has a width larger than the containing row. What happens is, instead of `column1` shrinking to still fit both columns in the same row line, `column1` fills the whole row as if it was `col-12` and `column2` drops down to a new line, hence wrapping the columns.

Is there way to prevent this behaviour and always keep both columns in the same line?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rROGya

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32846418/8583681) answer could help you

Comment: @Paulie_D reproduced here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYjWOo

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` is the issue. That's what you asked for, that's what you are getting.

Comment: @Paulie_D may I ask where that CSS styling got applied in OP's question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally the `flex-nowrap` class can be used on the row to prevent col wrapping in Bootstrap 4. In this case that won't work because of the wide, ellipsis content in the column.

Due to the way flexbox width is calculated (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457010/why-do-flex-items-wrap-instead-of-shrink) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465745/ellipsis-in-flexbox-container)), you should set a `width`, `min-width`, or `max-width` (*any width*) on the `flex-grow:1` column (`col`).

For example, set `width:0` on the `col`...

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
        <h4 class="ellipsis">aaaaaa..</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">
        something
    </div>
</div>

.col {
  width: 0;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/JKLUD0NLn4

Also, don't use both `col` and `col-auto` on the same column. The `flex-grow:1` of `col`, will prevent the `col-auto` from shrinking.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your answer, it seems that `flex-nowrap` causes column2 to be outside the row itself, to the right of column1, which takes up all the space

Comment: `width: 0;` does not work in Firefox. `min-width: 0;` does work in both Chrome and Firefox.